# How do I import sparkit-learn?

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

It says that all of the requirements for sparkit-learn are already satisfied, so I know that I have the module, but there are two strange things about the environment I'm working in.

One strange thing is that when I type `python` into the terminal, it doesn't load up the python shell even though python is installed.

The other strange thing is my question, I have IPython Notebook working and I can access it remotely, but I type `import splearn` and there's an error (see below).

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-656295d86158> in <module>()
----> 1 import splearn

ImportError: No module named splearn
```

If you don't think I installed it correctly please let me know what I need to do. Thank you!

**EDIT:** I was able to import it through the Pyspark shell, but I don't want to work within the Spark shell.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have a copy of the sparkit-learn source file from their github repo to import it in IPython Notebook. See below.

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

import pyspark

from pyspark import  SparkContext

cd sparkit-learn-master/

import splearn
```

Problem solved.